# Show $\mathcal L^p \otimes \mathcal L^q \subset \mathcal L^{p+q}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

How can I show that $\mathcal L^p \otimes \mathcal L^q \subset \mathcal L^{p+q}$ where  $p,q \in \mathbb Z_{\geq 1}$ ?

From my understanding, $\mathcal L^p = \mathcal L(\mathbb R^p)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets of $\mathbb R^p$ with the Lebesgue measure $\lambda^p$
and $\mathcal L^q = \mathcal L(\mathbb R^q)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets of $\mathbb R^q$ with the Lebesgue measure $\lambda^q$.

$\mathcal L^p \otimes \mathcal L^q$ is the product $\sigma$-algebra defined as $\mathcal L^p \otimes \mathcal L^q = \sigma\{A \times B: A \in \mathcal L(\mathbb R^p), B \in \mathcal L(\mathbb R^q) \}$

I have also the hint that every intersection of a set from $\mathcal L^p \otimes \mathcal L^q$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide us with information on the notation?

Comment: @Plop yes of course, sorry I forgot it completly!

Comment: Still not enough for me to understand. What does $\otimes$ mean, here?

Comment: We described product $\sigma$-algebras with $\otimes$